# How to read at90sc 12872rcft cards with android devices

Tags: nfc

I have to develop a proof of concept application able to read Atmel at90sc 12872rcft based smart cards. These cards are ISO/IEC 14443B compatible.

I've created a simple application that is able to read serial numbers on 14443A cards but does not even recognize that the 14443B card is in range with the phone. I'm using a nexus S with os version 4.1.2.

is there anyone that has experience on reading these cards willing to share experience ?

thanks,

Antonello

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus-S has a incredible bad antenna performance when it comes to ISO14443-B tags.

For your proof of concept you can try the following to improve the antenna performance:

- open the back-cover. On the upper left you see two contacts that connect to the NFC antenna of the Nexus-S. The antenna itself is glued to the back of the cover you have just removed.
- take a thin wire, approx. 20 to 25 cm. Make a coil out of it (three windings is good). Diameter between 4 and 5 cm. Connect this to the NFC antenna pins. Make sure that the coil is not located any metal parts (like the accumulator or the display or so).
- run your test program and present the tag to your ghetto antenna. You will now most likely now be able to detect your ISO14443-B tag and talk to it using the IsoDep interface.

The antenna is capacitively coupled, so you can even short it without doing any harm to the NFC chip.

Comment: Thanks Nils for your suggestion I've tryed it with no success... maybe the wire was too thick, maybe the power provided by Nexus electronics is not enough to power up the card, but results are the same, I can read ISO 14443-A tags with this external antenna but not ISO 14443-B ones. Can you suggest an android/Windows phone device able to power up those tags ? thanks